# ManyToMany properties

Tags: java, hibernate

This may be a stupid question or may be asked, But i didnt find which helped me.
Can anyone of you guys tell me what these properties described in ManyToMany relation do. And if there are any which i missed and should be used in ManyToMany mapping please help me with that too.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "customer_service",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"))
```

Comment: Read the API docs: [`@ManyToMany`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) [`@JoinTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) [`@JoinColumn`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) [`CascaseType`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) and come back when you have a more specific question. [The Java EE 6 Tutorial, Part VI - Persistence](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html) may also be useful to you:

Answer (score 0):

This is description of a many-to-many relationship between (I am guessing) `Customer` and `Service` tables. Technically all attributes are optional so:

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<Customer> services;
```

in `Service` would be fine (similar annotation on `Customer` side if the relationship is bidirectional).

Now assuming you have a some basic relational databases design knowledge:

- `@JoinTable` describes a join table, the one used to store relationships between customer and service. Each row contains one reference to customer and one to service. This table will be named `customer_service`
- `joinColumns` - definition of column(s) referencing the second side of the relationship - `customer_id`
- `inverseJoinColumns` - definition of column(s) referencing back to the starting side - `service_id` in this example.

Join- and inverse join columns are symmetric - if you define the many-to-many relationship on the other side you switch them. Otherwise everything will work from Java perspective but Hibernate will create a foreign key from `customer_id` to `Service` table and vice-versa and will insert values accordingly.